# Gaussian Curve Calculation (C++)

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram, gaussian

Given a histogram, perform a bi-means gaussian fitting.
This project fits two Gaussian curves to one histogram with an initial threshold value, and uses the curves to determine the ideal threshold value.  At each iteration, the histogram is divided into 2 parts, a Gaussian is called for each part of the histogram.

My calculations must be wrong considering my resultant curve is nonsensical. Can anyone spot what's going on here? I've included my functions for calculating the biMeans Gaussian curve, the fitGauss (computes Gaussian Curve), the mean, the variance, and the Gaussian value.

```
int biMeanGauss (int thrVal){
    double sum1, sum2, total = 0.0;
    int bestThr = thrVal;
    double minDiff = 99999999.0;

    for (int i = thrVal; i < (maxVal-offSet); i++) {
        set1DZero(GaussAry);

        sum1 = fitGauss(0, i);
        cout << "Sum1: " <<sum1 << endl;
        sum2 = fitGauss(i, maxVal);
        cout << "Sum2: " << sum2 << endl;
        total = sum1 + sum2;
        cout << "Total: " << total << endl;

        if (total < minDiff) {
            minDiff = total;
            bestThr = i; 
            cout << "Total < MinDiff, so BestThr: " <<bestThr << endl;
        }
        else;
    }
    return bestThr;
}

double fitGauss(int leftIndex, int rightIndex){
    double mean, var, sum = 0.0;
    double Gval;

    mean = computeMean(leftIndex, rightIndex, maxCount);
    var = computeVar (leftIndex, rightIndex, mean);

    for (int index = leftIndex; index <= rightIndex; index ++){
        Gval = computeGaussian(histAry[index], mean, var);
        sum += abs(Gval - histAry[index]);
        GaussAry[index] = (int)Gval;
        GaussImg[index][(int)Gval]= 1;
    }

    return sum;
};

double computeMean(int leftIndex, int rightIndex, int maxCount) {
    int mean, n, sum = 0;
    for (int i = leftIndex; i <= rightIndex; i++){
        sum += (i*histAry[i]);
        n++;
        if (histAry[i] > maxCount){
            maxCount = histAry[i];
        }
    }
    mean = (sum / (double) n);
    return mean;
}

double computeVar(int leftIndex, int rightIndex, int mean) {
    double var = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double n = 0;

    for (int i = leftIndex; i <= rightIndex; i++) {
        sum += histAry[i]*(i - mean) * (i - mean);
        n++;
    }

    var = (sum / n);
    return var;
}

double computeGaussian(int index, double mean, double var) {
    double Gval = 0;
    Gval = maxCount * exp(-(((index - mean)*(index - mean)) / (2 * var)));
    return Gval;
}
```